# Valor do botão não está passando corretamente

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Caros colegas.

Tenho um botão no bootstrap do qual pego o ID do usuário dessa forma:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="btn-salvar" value="<?php echo $jm->IdUsuarios; ?>" title="Ativado">Salvar</button>
```

Só que quando clico em salvar, ele só pega o do ID do primeiro usuário. Veja:

```
var valor = $('button#btn-salvar').val();
```

Como faria para que o ID dos outros usuários fossem passados para o código abaixo:

```
jQuery.ajax({
          url : "alterar.php?v=N&k="+valor,
          dataType : 'json',
          async : false,
          success : function(msg) {
          }
        });
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Podes juntar o código com o oscultador de evento? Acho que precisas usar `$(this).attr('value');` em vez de `$('button#btn-salvar').val();`. E deves evitar IDs duplas.

Comment: Perfeito Sérgio ... é isso aí... funcionou... obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tens um oscultador de eventos para quando um botão fôr clicado, então dentro da callback o `this` é o elemento clicado.

No elemento `button` podes usar `.attr('value')`. O `.val()` funcionaria também pois [é uma propriedade](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) do `button` mas semanticamente acho mais correto o `.attr()`.

Quando usas `$('button#btn-salvar')` o jQuery vai procurar um elemento por ID, como em HTML IDs têm de ser únicas ele vai retornar o primeiro ID que encontrar, mesmo que haja (erradamente) muitos.

Sugiro então usares:

```
$(this).attr('value');
```